# Magento 2.3.7 - Google Analytics 4 with Google Adwords

Tags: magento2.3, google-analytics, google-adwords

Regarding a Magento 2.3.7 website, I was asked to assist a company with Google Analytics 4 setup this week.  They are using Google Adwords and are now concerned about the conversion to Google Analytics 4.

Seeing that Google stops UA (Universal Analytics) at the end of this month (June 2023), and assuming that Google Analytics 4 is not going to be setup in time; are there any references to indicate if Google Adwords will be impacted in any way?

There is a Google Tag Manager XML feed setup for the data indexing for Google; but nothing else; Google Analytics 4 property is not tracking anything on the website, so is not working on the site it seems.

- What is the impact of not using Google Analytics 4 yet especially for Google Adwords?   The main concern is to understand if Ads will work or not.
- Any recommended way to setup the Google Analytics 4 script; again this is not a Magento 2.4x website, I compared the settings of the `Google API` settings with this documentation and they do not match:

[Google Analytics 4 for Magento 2.4](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/marketing/google-tools/google-analytics.html)

- I looked at `Magento_GoogleAnalytics` module on dev4-develop branch but it has not been changed in the last 2 years.  (What is the new Magento 2.4 module name?)